# Password Hash on PHP Server always looks the same

Tags: php, angularjs, hash, authentication, passwords

I've been provided with some PHP API ends for my project, recently I've faced a really weird issue, here is how it looks :

I have a set_customer API, when I send a request with Postman to register a user : 
1 - I get a success response ( from registration ),
2 - When I login with the loaded Username and Password, the login is Successful.

Now when I send the request to the same API from my AngularJS service,
1 - I still get a success response ( from registration ) which is OK,
2 - But when I try to login with the same credentials this time login Fails.

I have logged all the data I'm sending and receiving, the Username and the Password, the request payload and all input data, everything seem to be correct.
both when I'm Registering and when I'm Logging in.

The weird thing in a nutshell is when I register a user with Postman, I can login successfully afterwards but if I register the same user via a $http call, I can't login anymore!

P.S. I looked at the database and every time I register using Angular $http the Hash is the same. Even if I input different passwords.

Anyone with a possible solution ?! Even an assumption would be really appreciated !

Comment: `I register using Angular $http the Hash is the same. ` May be the registration script is the culprit.

Comment: You mean the PHP script or the Javascript ?

Comment: If we could see what you are doing, then just maybe, **we could help**

Comment: Both can be, either the JS file sends same data every time or PHP script is saving same password everytime.

Comment: @RiggsFolly What do you need me to provide you with for that ?

Comment: @Alok I've logged all the data from Javascript, they're all correct. I'm almost sure that it's not from the Client side, the thing is I'm trying to figure it out before I make a call to my backend developers so I can be specific and sure about the issue.

Comment: If you see the correct data being transferred to the API in `inspect element` then there must be something wrong in PHP registration script.

Comment: @Alok Thanks alok ! I've provided my team with the context of this post .

Comment: @Behzad You're welcome. :)